Upper bound on entire function
I try to tackle the following question:
Proof that there does not exist an entire function so that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ holds:
$$| f(z) | \geq \exp(|z|^2) - 1.$$
I am unsure how to tackle this kind of question. I noticed that the right side is obviously not an entire function, so this kind of removes the opportunity to work with Liouville (?).
It is apparent, that $f$ can not be a polynomial, because the bound is not a polynomial.
I thought of using Casorati-Weierstrass, but I am really unsure if this is applicable here?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Look at $\frac {z^{n}} {f(z)}$.

Suppose $f(0)\neq 0$. Then by the given inequality $f(z)\neq 0 $ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$.
We know that for any $n> 0$, and for $t>0$
$$e^{t} \geq 1+\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$
Thus,
$$e^{|z|^2}-1\geq \frac{|z|^{2n}}{n!}, $$
for all $n> 0$ and $z\neq 0$. Thus for all $z\neq 0$,
$$|f(z)| \geq \frac{|z|^{2n}}{n!}.$$
Or
$$n!\geq \begin{vmatrix} \frac{z^{2n}}{f(z)}\end{vmatrix},$$
for all $z\neq 0$. At $z=0$, anyway $n!\geq 0$. Thus the function $\frac{z^{2n}}{f(z)}$ is a bounded function and moreover it is entire and hence by Liouville, it must be constant. Thus, for every $n$,
$$z^{2n}= c(n) f(z),$$
where $c(n)\neq 0$. This forces that $f(0)=0$ against our assumption.
Now, if $f(0) = 0$, then letting $N$ to be order of $0$, we can write
$$f(z) = z^Ng(z), $$
where $g(0)\neq 0$. Then, $g(z)$ would be an entire function and for any $n>N$, we would have
$$|f(z)| \geq \frac{z^{2n}}{n!},$$
implying that
$$|g(z)| \geq \frac{|z^{2n-N}|}{n!}.$$
Now, again by the same arguments,
$$\frac{z^{2n-N}}{g(z)}$$
would be a constant function leading to the contradiction, as above, that $g(0)=0$.
Thus there cannot exist an entire function satisfying the given inequality.

By $$|f(z)|\geq\exp(|z|^2)-1,\quad z\in\mathbb C,$$
we know that
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}|f(z)|=+\infty,$$
so
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty.$$
This implies that $\infty$ is a pole of $f$, i.e. $f$ is a polynomial with degree at least one.
Suppose the degree $\deg(f)$ of $f$ is $n\geq1$ and
$$f(z)=a_nz^n+\cdots+a_1+a_0,\quad a_n\neq0,$$
Then $$|f(z)|\sim |a_nz^n|,\quad z\to \infty,$$
which leads to the contradiction with
$$|f(z)|\geq\exp(|z|^2)-1,\quad z\in\mathbb C.$$
So there cannot exist an entire function satisfying
$$|f(z)|\geq\exp(|z|^2)-1,\quad z\in\mathbb C.$$
Add: If $f$ is an entire function, then $f$ is one of the following three types:
(1) $f$ is a constant function($\infty$ is Removable Singularity);
(2) $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ at least one($\infty$ is Pole of order $n$ );
(3) $f$ is a transcendental entire function ($\infty$ is Essential Singularity).
